# what kind of array initialization is being done here (Basic Java)?

Tags: java, android

This is from [Android Developer's Website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html)

```
IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
try {
    ndef.addDataType("*/*");    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches.
                                   You should specify only the ones that you need. */
}
catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
}
intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
```

So here, `intentFiltersArray[0] = ndef`. What about `intentFiltersArray[1]` and beyond? What does having a `,` after `ndef` mean in the above code?

Again, it has another code example as

```
techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };
```

How is `techListsArray[][]` initialized here? I am guessing `techListsArray[0][0]=NfcF.class.getName()` (which should be `NfcF` shouldn't it?) but what about the other elements? Or does it only have a single element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So here, `intentFiltersArray[0] = ndef`. What about `intentFiltersArray[1]` and beyond?

There is no element at `[1]` or  "beyond".

You are creating an array with one element.  If you try to access `intentFiltersArray[1]` you will get an unchecked exception: [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

> What does having a comma after `ndef` mean in the above code?

It means nothing.  The Java language syntax allows a redundant comma at the end of the array initializer list.  (Ostensibly, it is to make source code generation easier ...)

---

Now your second example:

> How is techListsArray[][] initialized here?

It is initialized to a 1x1 array of arrays of Strings:

- `techListsArray[0]` is a `String[]` with one element.
- `techListsArray[0][0]` is a String ... the *fully qualified* name of the `NfcF` class; e.g. `"some.pkg.NfcF"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
```

is same as

```
intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef};
```

and now your question how this initialize

```
   IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef };
```

This will create an array of IntentFilter in onw go. It will define and declare array in single line with array size as 1 because there is only 1 element `ndef`.